# ASP.NET 4 jquery ajax webmethod call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-4.0, webmethod

In ASP.NET 3.5 I had this javascript on a page (default.aspx):

```
function getMoreNewsItems() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "default.aspx/LoadNewsItems",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });
}
```

With this in the code behind (default.aspx.cs):

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string LoadNewsItems() {
    return "test1";
}
```

I have a ScriptManager on the page with EnablePageMethods=true. All worked fine.

Now the project upgraded to ASP.NET 4.0 and is using the new url routing functionality. The AJAX call doesn't work anymore. In FireBug I see it returns the complete page, instead of the XML response.

What has changed in ASP.NET 4 that could be causing this error?

Answer (score 9):

Fixed,

Change

```
url: "default.aspx/LoadNewsItems",
```

To

```
url: '<%= ResolveUrl("default.aspx/LoadNewsItems") %>',
```

It has to do with the URL Routing.