# Calling button click from asp.net codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, click

I have two button as shown below:

**1st Button:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="First Button" CausesValidation="False"
     UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

**2nd Button:**

```
 <button type="reset" id="btn2" runat="server">
        <span>Second Button</span>
 </button>
```

Now If I click `btn1` I need to do some stuff and then I need to click `btn2` `automatically` at the end of the process which needs to perform some client side operations.

This is what I need to do:

```
Protected Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
//Do some Stuff

//Here I need to make btn2 click automatically
End Sub
```

As my `btn2` should do this:

```
$("#<%=btn2.ClientID%>").click(function () {
//perform some taks
}
```

Comment: So you want button one to submit the form and run your server side click event for it. Then after the page has loaded in the browser, you want it to run some code on the client to click button two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is this:

```
$("#<%= btn1.ClientID %>").click(function(){

    //do some stuff

    $("#<%= btn2.ClientID %>").trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how Server side code works. When button 1 will click then 1) all the client side code will run 2) and then server side click button will be called.

Currently you have mixed up server side code. What you can do is :

1. Perform the button 1 click code.
2. Put the code on button 2 click in a separate function and call that function at the end of button 1 code.

What you are trying to do is, unfortunately, incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you used to be able to emit script dynamicly using `ScriptManager`. You could try that to emit client script in `btn1_Click` that will click btn2 on the client when the page loads in the browser.

I'm with Beenish though. Without any other context, this sounds like a bad idea. I would try and turn `btn1_Click` into a webmethod and call it from the client using jquery. You might check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119067/asp-net-4-jquery-ajax-webmethod-call) for calling a webmethod from jquery